# Coffee script syntax higtlighting in nodeclipse

Tags: node.js, eclipse-plugin, nodeclipse

I am looking for an IDE for node.js development.
I have tried using Nodeclipse (nodejs plugin for eclipse), but it doesn't highlight cofeescript and stylus files.

Is that possible; or can I use another plugin with nodeclipse for syntax highlighting?

Comment: Also EditBox can do some help https://github.com/Nodeclipse/EditBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think https://github.com/Nodeclipse/coffeescript-eclipse is the plugin you'll need.